Shopware 6.6 plugin installation with composer dependency leads to an error
The installation worked flawless with Shopware 6.5 and whichbrowser/parser is the only dependency.
Shopware version: 6.6.3.0
Environment: dockware/dev:6.6.3.0 container
Required packages in the plugins composer.json
{
  "require": {
    "shopware/core": "^6.6.0.0",
    "whichbrowser/parser": "^v2.1.8"
  },
}

executeComposerCommands is enabled in the plugin base class
class MyPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public function executeComposerCommands(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

The following error message gets thrown:
In FilesystemRepository.php line 166:                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
file_get_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory    

The whole installation output:
[Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\PluginComposerRequireException]                                                                                                                                                           
  Could not execute "composer require" for plugin "MyPlugin (my-plugin:2.3.0). Output:                                                                                                                                   
  ./composer.json has been updated                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Running composer update my-plugin --with-all-dependencies                                                                                                                                                                    
  > pre-update-cmd: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->configureInstaller                                                                                                                                                               
  Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                                                              
  > pre-pool-create: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->truncatePackages                                                                                                                                                                
  Updating dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  Dependency resolution completed in 0.007 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Analyzed 624 packages to resolve dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Analyzed 2148 rules to resolve dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Lock file operations: 2 installs, 6 updates, 0 removals                                                                                                                                                                             
  Installs: whichbrowser/parser:v2.1.8, my-plugin:2.3.0                                                                                                                                                                        
  Updates: twig/twig:v3.8.0, zircote/swagger-php:4.10.0, twig/intl-extra:v3.8.0, shopware/conflicts:0.1.22, composer/class-map-generator:1.3.3, composer/composer:2.7.7                                                               
    - Locking my-plugin (2.3.0)                                                                                                                                                                                                
    - Upgrading composer/class-map-generator (1.3.2 => 1.3.3)                                                                                                                                                                         
    - Upgrading composer/composer (2.7.6 => 2.7.7)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    - Upgrading shopware/conflicts (0.1.20 => 0.1.22)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    - Downgrading twig/intl-extra (v3.10.0 => v3.8.0)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    - Downgrading twig/twig (v3.10.3 => v3.8.0)                                                                                                                                                                                       
    - Locking whichbrowser/parser (v2.1.8)                                                                                                                                                                                            
    - Upgrading zircote/swagger-php (4.9.3 => 4.10.0)                                                                                                                                                                                 
  Writing lock file                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)                                                                                                                                                                      
  > pre-operations-exec: Symfony\Flex\Flex_composer_tmp1->recordOperations                                                                                                                                                            
  Package operations: 2 installs, 6 updates, 0 removals                                                                                                                                                                               
  Installs: whichbrowser/parser:v2.1.8, my-plugin:2.3.0                                                                                                                                                                        
  Updates: zircote/swagger-php:4.10.0, twig/twig:v3.8.0, twig/intl-extra:v3.8.0, shopware/conflicts:0.1.22, composer/class-map-generator:1.3.3, composer/composer:2.7.7                                                               
    - Downloading whichbrowser/parser (v2.1.8)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    - Downloading zircote/swagger-php (4.10.0)                                                                                                                                                                                        
    - Downloading twig/twig (v3.8.0)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    - Downloading twig/intl-extra (v3.8.0)                                                                                                                                                                                            
    - Downloading composer/class-map-generator (1.3.3)                                                                                                                                                                                
    - Downloading composer/composer (2.7.7)                                                                                                                                                                                           
   0/6 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec                                                                                                                                                                                    
   3/6 [==============>-------------]  50%  1 sec                                                                                                                                                                                     
   6/6 [============================] 100%  1 sec                                                                                                                                                                                     
    - Installing whichbrowser/parser (v2.1.8): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                                     
    - Upgrading zircote/swagger-php (4.9.3 => 4.10.0): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                             
    - Downgrading twig/twig (v3.10.3 => v3.8.0): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                                   
    - Downgrading twig/intl-extra (v3.10.0 => v3.8.0): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                             
    - Upgrading shopware/conflicts (0.1.20 => 0.1.22)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    - Upgrading composer/class-map-generator (1.3.2 => 1.3.3): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                     
    - Upgrading composer/composer (2.7.6 => 2.7.7): Extracting archive                                                                                                                                                                
    - Installing my-plugin (2.3.0): Symlinking from custom/plugins/MyPlugin                                                                                                                                              
   0/6 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 sec                                                                                                                                                                                    
   5/6 [=======================>----]  83% < 1 sec                                                                                                                                                                                    
   6/6 [============================] 100% < 1 sec                                                                                                                                                                                    
  In FilesystemRepository.php line 166:                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    file_get_contents(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Exception trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php:166                                                                                                                                    
   Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a                                                                                                                                                                                    
   file_get_contents() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/FilesystemRepository.php:166                                                                                                                 
   Composer\Repository\FilesystemRepository->write() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:381                                                                                     
   Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->Composer\Installer\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:28                                                                                           
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:134                                                                                                                                   
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:42                                                                                                                 
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->done() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:135                                                                                                                                   
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:42                                                                                                                 
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->done() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:135                                                                                                                                   
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:42                                                                                                                 
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->done() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:66                                                                                                                                    
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:42                                                                                                                 
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->done() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:135                                                                                                                                   
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:42                                                                                                                 
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->done() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:135                                                                                                                                   
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:42                                                                                                                 
   React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->done() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:135                                                                                                                                   
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:168                                                                                                                         
   React\Promise\Promise->settle() at /var/www/html/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php:231                                                                                                                                          
   React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() at n/a:n/a                                                                                                                                                                        
   call_user_func() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:328                                                                                                                               
   Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->countActiveJobs() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/Loop.php:90                                                                                                           
   Composer\Util\Loop->wait() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:430                                                                                                            
   Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->waitOnPromises() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:405                                                                              
   Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->executeBatch() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:319                                                                                
   Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->downloadAndExecuteBatch() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:218                                                                     
   Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:827                                                                                                         
   Composer\Installer->doInstall() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:652                                                                                                                           
   Composer\Installer->doUpdate() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:298                                                                                                                            
   Composer\Installer->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:496                                                                                                                    
   Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:340                                                                                                  
   Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:279                                                                                                                         
   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1031                                                                                                                      
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:318                                                                                                                  
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:394                                                                                                  
   Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:169                                                                                                                                  
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:148                                                                                                    
   Composer\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Plugin/Composer/CommandExecutor.php:40                                                                                                         
   Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Composer\CommandExecutor->require() at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Plugin/PluginLifecycleService.php:697                                                                           
   Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\PluginLifecycleService->executeComposerRequireWhenNeeded() at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Plugin/PluginLifecycleService.php:126                                                    
   Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\PluginLifecycleService->installPlugin() at /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Plugin/Command/Lifecycle/PluginInstallCommand.php:69                                                        
   Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Command\Lifecycle\PluginInstallCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:279                                                                                   
   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1049                                                                                                                      
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:125                                                                                                 
   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:318                                                                                                     
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:79                                                                                                         
   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:169                                                                                                            
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php:49                                                                                                
   Symfony\Component\Runtime\Runner\Symfony\ConsoleApplicationRunner->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29                                                                                                           
   require_once() at /var/www/html/bin/console:17                                                                                               


6.6.3.0 is not 6.6.0.0, have you checked that?

In any case, a [mcve] would help, I'd expect it to give you enough focus to find the problem yourself.

I've tested it with 6.6.3.0, and still got the same result. And the two snippets are all you need to reproduce the issue, just create a base plugin and change/add my snippets

If you have a problem with using core features of Shopware, where you haven't written that much code on your own, you should probably report this to the maintainers of Shopware?

They are active here as well, I only kept the shopware tags now...

This is a bug in Shopware 6.6.3.0, I reported it to the manufacturer and it is being taken care of.
